# When installing Appcelerator CLI, appc setup command throws error

Tags: appcelerator

I am trying to install the appcelerator cli but keep running into an issue that I haven't been able to find a fix for.

When running the "appc setup" command I get the error "cannot find module 'C:\cyclic.js'" 
[link to full screen capture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tBkW.png)

I am running windows 7 64 bit and am following the directions here https://web.appcelerator.com/product/cli

*Edit: **If you are facing this same issue.  Uninstall Node, and Appcelerator.  Then make sure you install JDK 32 Bit (if using windows).  DELETE the NPM and Appcelerator folders in your C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\ directory.  Then reinstall Node (I had success with 32 bit) and the Appcelerator CLI.  That worked for me.**

Comment: What version of Node.js do you have installed?

Comment: I have node v0.10.37 installed

Comment: @ChrisBarber  see this was a bug fixed in 2.1.0 of type checker (https://github.com/bevry/typechecker/commit/2add790724c1ce2bd0d8b89df039259d5816099c) but appc-platform-sdk/getmac/extract-opts relies on 2.0.8 still (current is 4.1.0).

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get appcelerator to use the new version of typechecker?  I did "npm install typechecker -g" and tried running the "appc setup" command again but it gave me the same error with a reference to typechecker 2.0.8

Comment: The `typechecker` module is located in `.appcelerator\install\5.1.0\package\node_modules\typechecker`, which is in your home/user directory. We have not tested typechecker v2.1.0, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: How do I setup appcelerator to use typechecker v2.1.0 instead of v2.0.8?

Comment: @ChrisBarber the Appcelerator CLI is not finishing its setup because of this error.  I tried changing the dependancy in the package.json within getmac/extract-opts to use a different version of typechecker but it was overwritten when I ran the "appc setup" command again.  Is there another way for me to manually choose what version of typechecker appcelerator uses while doing its setup?

Comment: @user3512660 You should try using Node.js 4.2.6, then reinstall the Appcelerator CLI so that the native modules will be compiled against the correct Node version.

Answer (score 3):

Hello make sure you have node.js and JDK installed and environment variable set properly. For reference http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installation_and_Configuration. Now, As you already tried "appc setup". You need to delete all cache of previous installation try and try reinstalling again. Run,

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.appcelerator 
sudo npm uninstall -g appcelerator 
appc use latest
appc setup
```

Answer (score 0):

To setup the Appcelerator CLI, install Node.js, install the appcelerator module using the NPM CLI, then run the appc setup command to download and setup the latest CLI package. You can follow the guide [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Tasks-section-43306725_AppceleratorCLITasks-Installation). Also you can check this [link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_Node), if you experience an issue installing any of the npm packages.

Comment: That is the exact process I am following when I try to install Appcelerator. But when I run the appc setup command I get the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If still not solved, I suggest you to start from scratch. I see you work on Windows, true?:

- Remove install of NodeJS from "Uninstall programms" of control pannel
- Remove install of Appcelerator from "Uninstall programms" of control pannel
- Remove any folder from `C:\Program Files` or your `user's folder` referencing "node" "npm" or similar.
- Go to your `user's folder` and remove any .app or .appcelerator folder (could be hidden, so look it well)
- Don't forget to look in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming` (probably will be hidden)

Now you have only Java JDK installed (I'm using 1.8).

Proceed with a new appcelerator.EXE install, it must detect that you don't have Node and will download by itself the proper Node version.

Comment: Tried reinstalling the whole thing as suggested, but now Appcelerator Studio just gives me an error when it tries to update the CLI "Error encountered during update
Appcelerator CLI is currently installing or upgrading. Please wait until it has finished and retry your command afterwards."  I deleted all files related to node and appcelerator in my user directory before attempting this.

Comment: This happens when an installer is still working. Maybe the Appc installation didn't finished? Maybe NodeJS installation is in the background?

Comment: The installer finishes, but when I boot up appcelerator studio the first time it tries to update the command line interface (CLI) and breaks giving me the error

Comment: Umm, then I have no more clues. I did several installs for new Win 8 machines and all worked fine from scratch. Also used this method for my old two Win7 x64 and worked fine.

Comment: did you use 32 bit node or 64 bit node on your windows 7 install?

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I missed some NPM folders in my C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming folder.  Now I can install the command line tools successfully.

Comment: I use both, 32 and 64 bits, but great you where able to discover that forgotten folders. The best option is always remove all and start from scratch when there are problems. I edit the response to add that folders to the solution. Mark it as solution for future references.